# ADFS in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

i am new to ADFS and learning to implement it in my already developed application which is in asp.net c#.

[With the help of this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) i have added code in my application but now it gives error:

> Unable to load DLL 'ifsutils.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Can anyone help please?

Also, i am using Server2012R2 and framework 4.0, do i need to follow step 4 from the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link is for an extremely old version of AD FS and isn't the current guidance.

You need to give more details about the version of AD FS you have for use with your app. What operating system is the AD FS running on?

The latest developer related guidance for AD FS is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-scenarios-for-developers . Please review this and see if your app can accommodate the scenarios outlined. They are geared for using OAuth2 and OpenID Connect. This requires AD FS to be on Windows Server 2016.

But if you are not using AD FS on Windows Server 2016 and have AD FS on Windows Server 2012 R2 or below, then you should consider using WS-Federation instead. WIF modules allow you to use WS-Federation and you can use the guidance at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/wif-how-tos-index

There are other application stacks to also consider such as OWIN/Katana. See links such as http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/ . This uses WS-Federation.